# Echoing out mysqli data with php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get my head round mysqli so i can update my site and make it more secure. I have an article in a database and I am trying to echo it out like i would with mysql. I have seen loads and loads of posts here about basic mysqli but cannot find a way to get this to work. So i apologize if i have asked a question that has already been asked but what i have so far is mainly a result of what I have found here.

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\workshop\msqli-test.php on line 20
```

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
$DBServer = 'localhost';
$DBUser   = 'root';
$DBPass   = 'pass';
$DBName   = 'test_db';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql='SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title = "Simple Ideas For Your Website Logo."';

$row=$conn->query($sql);



echo "<div class='articlepreviewlayoutreadmore'><a href='".$row['link']."'>Read Full Article</a></div>";
echo "<img src='".$row['images']."' />";
echo "<h3><a href='".$row['link']."'>";
echo $row['title']."</a></h3>";
echo "<h6>Author: ".$row['author']."</h6>";
echo "<h6>Published:".$row['timestamp']."</h6>";
echo "<p>".$row['content']."</p>";
echo "<div class='articlepreviewlayoutreadmore'><a href='".$row['link']."'>Read Full Article</a></div>";

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this, i am getting old and keeping up to date with programming languages gets harder year after year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed a step. After you execute your query you get a result object returned. You then need to use that to get your results:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title = "Simple Ideas For Your Website Logo."';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That has sorted it. And just made my brain shift to solve 2 other problems i have been struggling with too. Was about to ask a question relating to one of them.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)